# Disable domain redirect

Tags: multisite, redirect, user-registration

Desired behavior:
`http://www.situationware.com` should stay at `www.situationware.com`, no registration required.

Currently wordpress is automatically redirecting to the Amazon hostname `ec2-107-22-241-162.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, requesting users register,  if I update wp-config.php by uncommenting `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` I end up with a redirect loop to http://situationware.com/wp-signup.php?new=situationware.com

As you'll see below I do have multisite installed as was working a few months ago before any upgrades to 3.6.1.

I installed the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin, but didn't help and didn't hurt.  I wasn't able to add a main site, but domain mapping screen was set.

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'ec2-107-22-241-162.compute-1.amazonaws.com' );
//define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'situationware.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Comment: You set your `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE`, perhaps you've set it incorrectly? Try removing that line

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.htaccess` file, it has to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And `wp-config.php` has to contain these lines:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'situationware.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Comment: Hi, gave it a go, same redirect loop issue once the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE is updated

Comment: Anyone have any other ideas ?  The less time it takes emergency responders to access information the quicker they can respond so this is much more than domain vanity.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
```

to

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
```

Comment: This _might_ solve the problem, but can you please explain _why_?